# how to serialize entities that have a one to many relationship and a pagination in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, configuration, foreign-keys, lazy-loading

I have a two Model for two table having foreign key relationship. I have to get record from both table in single request.

The structure of model is as follows:-

1. EmployeeRecord.cs

```
public partial class EmployeeRecord
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public tblEmployeeRecord()
        {
            this.countries = new HashSet<tblCountry>();
        }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string userRole { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Country> countries { get; set; }

    }
```

2.Country.cs

```
 public partial class Country
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

       public virtual EmployeeRecord employeeRecord { get; set; }
    }
```

3. EmployeeController.cs

```
 public class EmployeeRecordsController : ApiController
    {
        private EstorageEntitiesforCombineView db = new EstorageEntitiesforCombineView();

        // GET: api/EmployeeRecords
        public IEnumerable<EmployeeRecord> GetEmployeeRecords([FromUri]PagingParameterModel pagingparametermodel)
        {
             var source= db.EmployeeRecords.OrderBy(a => a.EmployeeId);

            // Get's No of Rows Count 
             if (pagingparametermodel.userRole == "HR")
            {
                 source= (from a in db.EmployeeRecords
                        where a.userRole == "HR"
                        select a).OrderBy(a => a.EmployeeId);
            }
            else if(pagingparametermodel.userRole == "eStorage Admin")
            {
                source = (from a in db.EmployeeRecords
                          where a.userRole == "eStorage Admin"
                          select a).OrderBy(a => a.EmployeeId);

            } else if(pagingparametermodel.userRole == "SharedService")
            {
                source = (from a in db.EmployeeRecords
                          where a.userRole == "SharedService"
                          select a).OrderBy(a => a.EmployeeId);

            }
             if(pagingparametermodel.toSearch == 1 && pagingparametermodel.userRole == "ALL")
            {
                source = (from b in db.EmployeeRecords
                          where b.Name.StartsWith(pagingparametermodel.name) 
                          select b).OrderBy(a => a.EmployeeId);

            }else if (pagingparametermodel.toSearch==1) {
                source= (from b in db.EmployeeRecords
                        where b.Name.StartsWith(pagingparametermodel.name) && b.userRole==pagingparametermodel.userRole
                        select b).OrderBy(a => a.EmployeeId);

            }
            int count = source.Count();

            // Parameter is passed from Query string if it is null then it default Value will be pageNumber:1  
            int CurrentPage = pagingparametermodel.pageNumber;

            // Parameter is passed from Query string if it is null then it default Value will be pageSize:20  
            int PageSize = pagingparametermodel.pageSize;

            // Display TotalCount to Records to User  
            int TotalCount = count;

            // Calculating Totalpage by Dividing (No of Records / Pagesize)  
            int TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)PageSize);

            // Returns List of Customer after applying Paging   
            var items = source.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList();

            // if CurrentPage is greater than 1 means it has previousPage  
            var previousPage = CurrentPage > 1 ? "Yes" : "No";

            // if TotalPages is greater than CurrentPage means it has nextPage  
            var nextPage = CurrentPage < TotalPages ? "Yes" : "No";

            // Object which we are going to send in header   
            var paginationMetadata = new
            {
                totalCount = TotalCount,
                pageSize = PageSize,
                currentPage = CurrentPage,
                totalPages = TotalPages,
                previousPage,
                nextPage
            };

            // Setting Header  
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Paging-Headers", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationMetadata));
            // Returing List of Customers Collections  
            return items;

        }
}
```

I want the response as follows :-

```
[{
        "tblCountries": [
            {
                "CountryId": 265,
                "EmployeeId": 350,
                "CountryName": "INWEST"
            }
        ],
        "EmployeeId": 350,
        "Name": "ABC",
        "userName": "abc@mail.com",
        "userRole": "HR",
        "id": nbh546652n45
 }]
```

But the response is as follows:-

```
[{
        "tblCountries": [],
        "EmployeeId": 350,
        "Name": "ABC",
        "userName": "abc@mail.com",
        "userRole": "HR",
        "id": nbh546652n45
 }]
```

I have also tried, `Include(a => a.countries)` as follows:-

```
source= (from a in db.EmployeeRecords
            where a.userRole == "HR"
           select a).Include(a => a.countries).OrderBy(a => a.EmployeeId);
```

But i am getting following error:-

```
<ExceptionMessage>
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace/>
<InnerException>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
Object graph for type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[eStorageApi.Models.tblCountry, eStorageApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
</ExceptionType>
```

Tried including these LOCs into webApiConfig.cs:-

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling= Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

Still getting the same error.

Comment: Entities represent data. What your API returns needs to be defined and selected from the entity rather than attempting to pass back an entity directly. (yes, many examples out there do it, still a very bad/lazy practice) Define the structure and fields you want to return as a POCO DTO class, and use `.Select()` or AutoMapper `.ProjectTo()` to populate it. It's not advisable to give a client access to the database, even to do a SELECT * FROM WHERE against a table, which is what returning entities amounts to.

Answer (score 1):

Project your domain model into something else before returning it from your api. This better controls the response data format and if a property gets added (such as ssn) it doesn't get inadvertently exposed. This also has the added benefit of fixing your cyclical references.

```
return items.Select(i => new { 
    i.Name,
    i.Username,
    ...
    Countries = i.Countries.Select(c => new {
            c.CountryId,
            c.CountryName,
            ...
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the relationship between employeeRecord and countries. Try with this:

```
 source= db.EmployeeRecords.Include(e => e.countries).Select(c => c.employeeRecord)
           .Where(a => a.userRole == "HR");
```

And when you do the request you need specify text: Application/Json

Comment: Hi @mlvictor i Use as below give same output :

Comment: var source = db.tblEmployeeRecords.Include(e => e.tblCountries).OrderBy(a => a.EmployeeId);